# Save as txt in mail?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I would like to use Elementary as default OS, but for the moment there are still a bunch of little obstacles to do so.

I save my official and professional mail-messages as text. This because I want to back it up and be able to search and read prior mails, without the use of a mail-client.

I think using Elementary while installing a bunch of other applications, is pointless, because then it is easier to use a distro which already has all those applications. The beauty of Elementary is it's simplicity, which would be lost if I stack it with other applications besides the original ones (this is different for applications which are just missing).

Any thoughts/solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can save as pdf. Print > Print to File actually saves the email as pdf.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's an option. It's not ideal, because a pdf is bigger and not easy to edit. A .txt or .rtf file is smaller and you can open and edit it in almost anything.

Comment: I guess you can request this feature on github.